# Having trouble with this python error

Tags: python, math, numpy, matplotlib, calculus

Hey guys I am trying to solve this math problem

Using data in a car magazine, we constructed the mathematical model

y=100e^(-0.0482t)

for the percentage of cars of a certain type still on the road after t years.  Using Python, determine the rate of change of the percent of cars still on the road after 5 years.

I came up with this code but I keep getting a syntax error

```
from sympy import  *
import numpy as np
x= Symbol('X')
y= 100*exp(-0.0482X)
yprime=y.diff(x)
yprimerep=y.diff(5)
print   (yprime)
print   (yprimerep)
```

**Error:
line 4
y= 100*exp(-0.0482X)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Do you know what is wrong here? Either with my math or with my code?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `-0.0482X` is no valid number.

Comment: I was trying to perform 100e^(-0.0482t) so that -0.0482X is from that. I changed the code to be y= 100 * exp(-0.0482 * X) but still got a name error message

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

y= 100 * exp(-0.0482 * x)

Comment: J. Murray - I tried what you suggested and I am now getting the error
"NameError: name 'X' is not defined"

Comment: Try changing the case of X to x (you have a variable declared as **x**, and Python is a case-sensitive language)

Comment: ok I tried that, now im getting these error 
Can't calculate 1-th derivative wrt 5.

sigh im beginning to think my entire code is incorrect.